# How $E_\lambda$ is a projection?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, projection

[image]

Since the sum of two projections need not be a projection then how at [Page 494](https://docs.ufpr.br/%7Eeidam/2019/2/CM075/Kreyszig.pdf) it is claimed that $E_\lambda$ is a projection?

Comment: It depends on what the $P_1, ..., P_n$ are, which you are not telling us.

Comment: @Paul:$P_1,P_2,...P_n$ are mentioned as Projections in the text

Comment: I guess the projections $P_j$ are mutually orthogonal.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Yes,at page 493 $P_j$ is mentioned as an orthogonal projection

Comment: What I meant was $P_jP_k=0$ for $j\neq k.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc:Got it now... thank  you